# Detect stop button Xcode pressed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is it possible to add in AppDelegate to detect when the app stopped running after pressing the Stop button here:
[image]

I know about `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationWillTerminate`, but those won't run when tapping the Stop button in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't detect that as it's IDE internal work , also you mix between 2 separate things these 2 delegate methods `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationWillTerminate` can be tested when you leave the app (Swipe up or go to home screen in your iphone/simulator without closing it)